# Why is there no `keyCode` value on the synthetic event in react using Semantic UI's Search component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, semantic-ui-react

**I have created a simple Search with Semantic UI's Search Component like this:**

```
<Search
    value={searchString}
    onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
    showNoResults={false}
    size="massive"
    placeholder="eg. Huberdo"
    input="text"
  />
```

This is my `onSearchChange` func:

```
const onSearchChange = (e, data) => {
console.log(e.keyCode);
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
  submit();
}
setSearchString(e.target.value);
};
```

Here is a minimum example of my problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-leaf-7mzvo?fontsize=14

**The Problem:**

When I console log the event, I can't find any information about the keyCode that was pressed. `e.keyCode` is undefined as is `e.charCode`.

I need this so I can submit the search when the user hits enter.

***Where is the keyCode hidden?***

According to the Semantic UI Doc's the func gets passed in a normal synthetic react event. 
`e.target.value` is working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding an `onKeyDown` prop:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Search } from "semantic-ui-react";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState("");

  const handleEnter = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      submit();
    }
  };

  const onSearchChange = (e, data) => {
    setSearchString(e.target.value);
  };

  const submit = () => {
    console.log("submitted");
  };

  return (
    <Search
      value={searchString}
      onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
      showNoResults={false}
      size="massive"
      placeholder="eg. Huberdo"
      input="text"
      onKeyDown={handleEnter}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thx I wasn't aware that the normal events also function on the Semantic UI Component, since it's not in their documentation's docs. Thank you :)

Comment: It's not `onKeyPress` it's `onKeyDown` that works for me. `onKeyPress` the code is always 0. You might want to make that little change in the solution. But your answer is very much appreciated and thanks again :)

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke Oops, sorry. Updated now! :)